# mysql schedueld events 'execute_at' timestamp

Tags: mysql, events

i'm unable to execute an event.
i can set it, without error, for 1 minute, or 5 seconds, in the future, but it never runs.  checking the internal mysql tables, i get conflicting timestamps for the execution time. there are two tables i'm aware of for this:

1 - table, mysql.event ----------------------------- returns -- 'execute_at' = 2011-10-24 00:44:33
2 - table, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS - returns -- 'execute_at' = 2011-10-23 17:44:33

the first one seems to be UMT, and the second is my system's time zone, gmt.  despite the second one being correct, nothing happens. i can successfully run the events' DO statement, and update my table.

```
create event test.eTest
on 
    schedule at current_timestamp + interval 1 minute
do  
    insert into user(fName, lName, dtStamp)
    values('jj', 'adams', now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should start scheduler thread.

- Check if it started - `SELECT @@global.event_scheduler`
- Start scheduler using this command - `SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;`
- After you can work with events.

More information here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html

Also, try visual event editor in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (Experess Edition is free).